# How would I send multiple different values of different variables from popup.js to inject.js so those can be used in the inject.js script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Hi I am unsure on how would I send set variables from popup.js to inject.js. Lets say I've got these variables in popup.js:

```
// popup.js file
var year = "New Year"
var month = "New Month"
var day = "New Day"
```

Now I would like to send each an every single one to be used in inject.js script and I am unsure how I would do that. Any ideas?

```
// inject.js file
// some how import the values over from the popup.js
console.log(year + ", " + month +  ", " + day)
```

If anyone has any idea on how to do this please help I'am very stuck on this and I am beginner in coding so sorry if this is a question that you have seen before or its repetitive I just am looking for help thank you.

P.S This is for a google extension so if any ideas could be compatible with google chrome would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

The old school way of doing it is to use the window and assign your variable to some properties of it. If this is a small project and you just want to get it done this is very simple.

In popup.js do ,

```
window.myVars = {
                    "year": year,
                    "month": month,
                    "day": day
                };
```

Now on inject.js

```
console.log(window.myVars.year + ", " + window.myVars.month +  ", " + window.myVars.day)
```

The problem with this is you are polluting the global scope. If another javascript file ( maybe a third party library ) uses window.myVars you could run into a problem. This approach is much harder to debug and garbage collection may also be affected.

A much modern approach but would be to use the local storage API.

```
localStorage.setItem("year",year); // In popup.js
localStorage.getItem("yera"); // In inject.js
```

If you can use the latest es module feature then you could also do,

```
export const getYear = (() => year ); // In popup.js
export const getMonth = (() => month );
export const getDay = (() => day );
```

then in inject.js ,

```
import getYear,getMonth,getDay from ./popup.js

console.log(getYear());
```

Comment: I am not really sure about the import syntax ( this is an approximation based on what I know from typescript ). Just google imports in javascript. Anyway, I hope the first solution is enough for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help I've tried all of them but still the values when I try and use them in inject.js are still null so not sure what to do now. Thank you

Comment: Are you sure popup.js is being run and it is running on the same window?

Comment: No so my popup.js script opens a new window which then the inject.js script runs in the new window opened. And I found another way to fix my problem but it involves in me getting the value of an input box from popup.html to inject.js any idea on this?

Comment: Did you try using a service worker? They are shared between pages ( for efficient caching ).

Comment: I think I am giving up on the code I have I have been trying loads of stuff for the past year and the problem is probably very easy to fix but I have no clue. I have tried to understand most of this stuff but I am a beginner and I just can't. All I need is to transfer 3 input box values and  2 radio button values to an Inject file and I can't do it think code is just not my thing